# Minio console login fails in cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minio

I run Minio on a kubernetes cluster since May. Everything worked fine. Since the last action, updated ingress from Traefik to Nginx ingress, I cannot login to the Minio Console anymore.

I do not really know if this happen before or after the ingress update. But in all I think this is not the reason.

The secret is still there in the cluster and it looks well.

The common Minio login to browse the buckets works perfect. But not the Minio Console.

The pod is always writing in the pod log (Lens):

```
2021-11-29 22:01:17.806356 I | 2021/11/29 22:01:17 operator.go:73: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
2021-11-29 22:01:17.806384 I | 2021/11/29 22:01:17 error.go:44: original error: invalid Login
```

No word about an error, but always `Unauthorized` inside the login screen. Anybody here with a similar problem in the past?

Comment: Please provide more information about your current setup - which Kubernetes version are you using, which solution did you use to setup a cluster (kubeadm or some cloud provider solution etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

The auth issue can be faced due to an expired `apiserver-kubelet-client.crt`. If it's expired, try to renew the cert and restart the apiserver.

In order to do this:

- check if the cert is expired
- remove expired certificates(.crt)
- execute `kubeadm alpha phase certs all`

Note this:

```
# for kube-apiserver
--kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
--kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key

# for kubelet
--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
```

**Solution 2:**

While you've deployed cluster on Kubernetes before, you've should created Kubernetes manifest. You can try to delete them(service account, role, rolebinding) and create them once again:

- Remove Service Account:

`kubectl delete serviceaccount --namespace NAMESPACE_NAME SERVICEACCOUNT_NAME`

- Remove Cluter Role Binding:

`kubectl delete clusterrolebinding CLUSTERROLEBINDING_NAME`

- Remove Minio directory:

`rm -rf ./minio`

- Create the Service Account, Role, RoleBinding:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: minio-serviceaccount
  labels:
    app: minio

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: minio-role
  labels:
    app: minio
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  resourceNames:
  - "minio-keys"
  verbs:
  - get

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: minio-role-binding
  labels:
    app: minio
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: minio-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: minio-serviceaccount
```

> Make sure that the Minio pods can access the Minio keys stored in the previously created Secret or create new secrets.

- Run helm init command:

`helm init --service-account=minio-serviceaccount`

- Recreate your Minio pod
- Reinstall the charts